# XPath - Verify if current node has same value of any sibling

Tags: xml, xpath

In XPath 1.0, is there a way to verify if current node value has same value of any sibling?

For example, `Name` in `Item3` would return `true` while `Name` in `Item2` would return `false`

```
<Item1>
  <Name>Name1</Name>
  <Id>123</Id>
</Item1>
<Item2>
  <Name>Name2</Name>
  <Id>124</Id>
</Item2>
<Item3>
  <Name>Name1</Name>
  <Id>125</Id>
</Item3>
```

Comment: FYI, `Name` in `Item3` isn't a sibling of `Name` in `Item1` or `Item2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that current context element is one of the `ItemX` element, you can use the following :

```
self::*[Name=following-sibling::*/Name or Name=preceding-sibling::*/Name]
```

above xpath returns current context element if there is sibling `ItemX` element having same `Name` value, and otherwise it returns nothing.

Comment: Is it going to consider all items at same level? I need it to compare Name in Item3 against Name in Item2 and Item1

Comment: Yes, it is considering all items at the same level : `Item1`, `Item2`, & `Item3` in your XML sample

Comment: While this is useful and correct, it doesn't answer the question asked: "verify if current node value has same value of any sibling". However it may answer the question that was meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Name">
    <!-- make the evaluation -->
    <xsl:variable name="curname" select="text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="multiple" select="count(//Name[text()=$curname]) &gt; 1"/>

    <!-- show result -->
    <xsl:value-of select="../Name[1]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$multiple"> MULTIPLE</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not($multiple)"> SINGLE</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```